# C: how to kill a child process using signal (ctrl + \ , ctrl + c) like in bash

Tags: c, bash

I want to simulate the signals in bash but using C.

I want to kill a child process using signal function (`void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);`).

the problem I faced is how can I pass the PID of the child function without using global vars?

I reached so far:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t is_child = 0;

void signal_handler(int sig) {
    char parent_str[] = "this is ctrl + c in the parent prosess\n";
    char child_str[] = "this is ctrl + c in the child prosess\n";
    signal(sig, signal_handler);
    if (sig == SIGINT) {
        if (is_child) {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, child_str, sizeof(child_str) - 1);
        } else {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, parent_str, sizeof(parent_str) - 1);
        }
    }
    else if (sig == SIGQUIT)
    {
        if (is_child) {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "this is ctrl + \\ in the child prosess\n", sizeof("this is ctrl + \\ in the child prosess\n") - 1);
        } else {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "this is ctrl + \\ in the parent prosess\n", sizeof("this is ctrl + \\ in the parent prosess\n") - 1);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pid_t pid, pgid;

    (void)argv;
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGQUIT, signal_handler);
    pid = fork();
    assert(pid != -1);
    if (pid == 0) {
        is_child = 1;
        printf("child pid, pgid = %ju, %ju\n", (uintmax_t)getpid(), (uintmax_t)getpgid(0));
        while (1);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    printf("parent pid, pgid = %ju, %ju\n", (uintmax_t)getpid(), (uintmax_t)pgid);
    while (1);
}
```

but as you see I used a global var...

how can I do this without the global var

Comment: I wouldn't worry about using a global variable in this case.  When a concept is truly global, there's much less disincentive to using a global variable to record it.

Comment: Use [signal()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) (or equivalent) to *HANDLE* a signal in your process.  Use [kill()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) to *SEND* a signal.  Q: what's the cleanest, most straightforward way to "know" your child's PID?  A: By saving the return from fork().  *SO WHAT* if it happens to be a "global variable"?  What exactly is the problem?  Why should you care?

Comment: You don't need a global variable, if the call of `fork()` is in the same translation unit as the call of `kill()`. It just needs to be `static`.

Comment: The idea that signals come from Bash and have to be "simulated" in C is so crazy it's not even wrong.

Comment: See also [this presumably-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67743236) by the same poster.